# How does my machine know it needs updating when it is air-gapped?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04, software-update

I have a machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has a wifi card, but I have turned off wifi, and as an extra precaution, I have disabled networking. So, in my mind, though the wifi card is still installed, I assumed the machine was more or less air-gapped. Yet, this morning I saw a notice that Ubuntu was ready for an upgrade. How did my machine that there was an update available? How is this possible? I found this fascinating, can someone explain?

**Edit**

I am getting updates for:

- Software
- Ubuntu Software
- Bazel
- Common CA certificates
- Transitional package for snapd
- and several for Ubuntu base

Without having more knowledge about networking answering, I would have to ask more questions to answer this question (how can I verify the date of my last internet connection, Can an installed wifi card still receive signal for updates?, etc...) I have a feeling it has to do with the wifi card being installed, but cannot substantiate this with any evidence.

Also, the 'apt list --upgradeable' command showed the several of these upgrades as well, so that was a no-go.

If anyone knows a command that can help me verify (prove) when my last internet connection was, please let me know it (a quick google search didn't do the trick). Otherwise, I am going to drop this question.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: It does not.  If it was saying it was ready for an upgrade, then at some point, it was connected to the internet.  Only other possibility is it was once connected to the internet, downloaded an update to the repository at some point, and has been asking you for awhile to update.

Comment: @Ramhound, it was connected to the internet at one point, but hasn't been for over a month. Is it reasonable to assume that these update times were pre-planned that far in advance? That is what was perplexing to me. --hasn't been asking for a while.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that any software company would know when they were going to push updates over a month in advance.

Comment: They didn't, I am saying you were connected at some point before that, without you knowing.  All i know is machine that was truly air gapped, would NEVER ask you to update.  The fact I have several dozen, various variants of Linux, know a thing or two about air gapped machines.

Comment: I am not questioning your knowledge about air-gapped machines. As I said, mine is only pseudo-air gapped. The network card is installed, but the wifi is turned off, and after that I turned off networking. I am 100% sure that these features have not been turned on in over a month, and I am 100% sure that it just started asking me to update recently (I don't check the machine every day), I only use this machine for training NNs. Could this perhaps have something to do with the wifi card being installed, regardless of network connectivity settings?

Comment: You are trying to say that I enabled wifi and networking at some point, correct? Unless someone broke into my home and enabled networking and wifi, then disabled them, the machine has not been connected for over a month, as I have said. I am 100% certain... I am not trying to be obtuse, it is just that your logic doesn't hold up in my mind

Comment: You didn't indicate what updates it wants to install by the way.

Comment: Are you sure the updates haven't been there for a month and it just started nagging about applying these updates after X days? Is it your UI telling you?

Comment: @ Mikael Kjaer, yet it is my UI telling me, I suppose it is possible the updates were available previously but not prompted by my UI.... I don't really know at this point.

Comment: The only notification you should get in a true air-gapped machine is a notification about the CA, when it expires.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for working with me on this issue. I am going to drop it at this point, but just wanted to say I tested the 'tcpdump' command earlier this morning and have left it on (with wifi AND networking off, for sure), and I am receiving transmission from various servers (ubuntu.com, googleapis.com). Not what exactly that means because networking isn't my forte, but I feel like this is something that shouldn't happen. I thought it might support my wifi card closing the air-gap argument. Anyway, thanks again for the information and help you've provided.

Comment: "Not what exactly that means" - It means that machine is connected to the internet.  If you had no internet connection then you wouldn't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

no updates are available for your system. Simply the system thus tries to deceive you and force you to connect to the Internet and then it will receive a list of updates. If you now want to get a list of updates in the terminal ( `apt list --upgradable` ) - it will be empty. The update manager is configured to periodically receive a list of updates, but without the Internet, it tries and does not work. But by default, it assumes that there is an update. That motivates you to connect and check. **this is if indeed you did not exactly include wi-fi**

Comment: What are you basing this on? Our air-gapped Ubuntu machines without internet doesn't have this behavior. That's Ubuntu versions from 10.04 to 16.04.

Comment: I base myself on the behavior of my own systems on xubuntu 16.04 and linux mint. especially the mint suffer from this. When the system did not turn on for more than a month, and then it turned on without the Internet, the update icon always appears

Comment: Then it's not truly air-gapped and it's impossible to say what happened. On our truly air-gapped systems we don't see anything like this.

Comment: @Alex_Krug, can you provide documentation that the update manager exhibits this behaviour, because it sounds a bit farfetched.

Comment: @Zroach - The documentation does not exist.  What is described here is fiction, pure fiction, my experience across dozens of air-gapped machines matches Mikael's.